# How to move a Sprite continuously in right to left position(Parallax)?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocos2d-iphone, parallax

My problem is: I need to move my sprite continuously from right to left position(orientation is landscape)
 i have searched and found the tutorial by Ray(thanks to him)
but the image does't seem to be scrolling continuously my code is

```
-(id) init
{   
// always call "super" init
    if( (self=[super init])) {

        CGSize screenSize = [CCDirector sharedDirector].winSize;

        // 1) Create the CCParallaxNode
        backgroundNode = [CCParallaxNode node];
        [self addChild:backgroundNode z:-1];

        // 2) Create the sprites we'll add to the CCParallaxNode
        Back = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"bg_front_spacedust.png"];
        Back.rotation = -90;
        Back1 = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"bg_front_spacedust.png"];
        Back1.rotation = -90;

        // 3) Determine relative movement speeds for space dust and background
        CGPoint dustSpeed = ccp(0.1, 0.1);

        // 4) Add children to CCParallaxNode
        [backgroundNode addChild:Back z:0 parallaxRatio:dustSpeed positionOffset:ccp(screenSize.width/2, screenSize.height/2)];
        [backgroundNode addChild:Back1 z:1 parallaxRatio:dustSpeed positionOffset:ccp(screenSize.width,0)];

        // 5) Enable updates
        [self scheduleUpdate];
}
    return self;
}

- (void)update:(ccTime)dt {

    // 1) Update background position
    CGPoint backgroundScrollVel = ccp(0,-1000);
    backgroundNode.position = ccpAdd(backgroundNode.position, ccpMult(backgroundScrollVel, dt));

    // 2) Check for background elements moving offscreen
    NSArray *spaceDusts = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:Back, Back1, nil];
    for (CCSprite *spaceDust in spaceDusts) {
        if ([backgroundNode convertToWorldSpace:spaceDust.position].x < -spaceDust.contentSize.width) {
            [backgroundNode incrementOffset:ccp(2*spaceDust.contentSize.width,0) forChild:spaceDust];
        }
    }
}
```

the image is of size 1024 X 320
can anybody guide me on this issue
thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You can find step-by-step guide on parallax here:
http://www.raywenderlich.com/3611/how-to-make-a-space-shooter-iphone-game
Just scroll a little bit until you find *Adding Parallax Scrolling* section.

But I would recommend to go through the whole tutorial. It is really good one.

Answer (score 0):

lets try it..

```
CCSprite *bird  = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"bird.png"];
        bird.position = ccp(100,80);
        [map addChild:bird];


        id move = [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:4.2 position:ccp(400, 80)];
        id move1 = [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:4.2 position:ccp(200, 80)];
        [bird runAction:[CCRepeatForever actionWithAction:[CCSequence actions:move,move1, nil]]];
```